# URL Structure Parent to Child Relationship With Static Files

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing

Currently I can not show site structure in the url IE www.site.com/parent-page/child-page without creating a subdirectory at the root.  Is there an easy way to dynamically create the parent to child relationship other than creating subdirectories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you're doing. If each page is its own script, then the directory structure probably helps keep things sane - I'm not sure there's a way to remove the directories and still keep the files in order.

But **if you're using some kind of bootstrap** you can simply rewrite all non-existing files/directories to a script. That script (or a script it calls) would then be responsible for parsing the request and determining what page to display.

This sample mod_Rewrite is taken from the end [of this Zend Framework section](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.quick-start.html#zend.application.quick-start.manual):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) docs are a good reference.